# executing shell command in background from script

Tags: bash, unix, shell

how can I execute a shell command in the background from within a bash script, if the command is in a string?

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
cmd="nohup mycommand";
other_cmd="nohup othercommand";

"$cmd &";
"$othercmd &";
```

this does not work -- how can I do this?

Comment: See also [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Leave off the quotes

```
$cmd &
$othercmd &
```

eg:

```
nicholas@nick-win7 /tmp
$ cat test
#!/bin/bash

cmd="ls -la"

$cmd &


nicholas@nick-win7 /tmp
$ ./test

nicholas@nick-win7 /tmp
$ total 6
drwxrwxrwt+ 1 nicholas root    0 2010-09-10 20:44 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 nicholas root 4096 2010-09-10 14:40 ..
-rwxrwxrwx  1 nicholas None   35 2010-09-10 20:44 test
-rwxr-xr-x  1 nicholas None   41 2010-09-10 20:43 test~
```

Comment: thanks. it's necessary to leave off the semicolons too as far as i can tell.

Comment: Also make sure you do **not** put quotations around `$cmd`. If you do, it will try to run a command called `"ls -la"` instead of `ls` with the switches `-la`.

Comment: `cmd='some-command "with arguments"'; $cmd` is not **at all** the same as `some-command "with arguments"`. It'll fail if you have quoting in your argument list; it'll fail if you need to control when globs are and are not expanded; it'll fail if running code that depends on brace expansion or parameter expansion at execution time. See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050): *I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but complex cases always fail!*.

Answer (score 82):

Building off of `ngoozeff`'s answer, if you want to make a command run **completely** in the background (i.e., if you want to *hide its output* and *prevent it from being killed* when you close its Terminal window), you can do this instead:

```
cmd="google-chrome";
"${cmd}" &>/dev/null & disown;
```

- `&>/dev/null` sets the command’s `stdout` and `stderr` to `/dev/null` instead of inheriting them from the parent process.
- `&` makes the shell run the command in the background.
- `disown` removes the “current” job, last one stopped or put in the background, from under the shell’s job control.

In some shells you can also use `&!` instead of `& disown`; they both have the same effect. Bash doesn’t support `&!`, though.

Also, when putting a command inside of a variable, it's more proper to use `eval "${cmd}"` rather than `"${cmd}"`:

```
cmd="google-chrome";
eval "${cmd}" &>/dev/null & disown;
```

If you run this command *directly in Terminal*, it will show the PID of the process which the command starts. But *inside of a shell script*, **no output** will be shown.

Here's a function for it:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Run a command in the background.
_evalBg() {
    eval "$@" &>/dev/null & disown;
}

cmd="google-chrome";
_evalBg "${cmd}";
```

Also, see: [Running bash commands in the background properly](https://web.archive.org/web/20160616013356/https://felixmilea.com/2014/12/running-bash-commands-background-properly/)

Comment: @user248237dfsf @GreenRaccoon23 `eval "${cmd}"` is surely much better than just `${cmd}`. I believe that's what you meant as `"${cmd}"` will fail for cases like: `cmd='ls -l'`. Also, `${cmd}` itself is not the perfect solution as it will fail for cases using expansions done before parameter expansion. So for example for `cmd='touch file{1..5}'`.

Comment: `eval "$@"` is buggy -- if someone expects `"$@"` to ensure that arguments are passed separately from each other, using `eval` defeats the point (by concatenating all its arguments together into a single string, and then evaluating it). Better to *either* use `"$@"` (expecting arguments to be pre-split), or `eval "$1"` (expecting exactly one argument formatted for parsing).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy What's an example of when `eval "$@"` is buggy? I can't think of one. I can think of cases where `"$@"` would be buggy though, like indirect variables. `eval "${1}"` would ignore multiple arguments too, as you pointed out. `eval "$@"` would handle both of those edge cases. I do agree that `eval "${1}"` should be enough though because your code should be consistent in the way it calls that function. Requiring the quotes in `_evalBg "${cmd}"` instead of `_evalBg ${cmd}` will make the code more manageable in the long run.

Comment: @GreenRaccoon23, as a demonstrative case, consider `set -- printf '%s\n' "first argument" "second argument"` -- `"$@"` will work on its own, `eval "$@"` won't.

Comment: @GreenRaccoon23, ...and yes, I'm positioning ignoring multiple arguments as a feature, not a bug, on the rationale that it's better to not support a case at all than to support it badly: Either accept a single string with code to run (`eval "$1"`), or accept a list of arguments (`"$@"`); but `eval "$@"` is behaving the exact same way as `eval "$*"` would, with all the bugs that implies.

Comment: @GreenRaccoon23, (...`for arg; do eval "$arg"; done &` would be reasonable too -- accepting a list of separate shell commands to be individually executed in a single background process -- but "concatenate all our arguments and parse the resulting string" is just error-prone).

Answer (score 3):

This works because the it's a static variable.
You could do something much cooler like this:

```
filename="filename"
extension="txt"
for i in {1..20}; do
    eval "filename${i}=${filename}${i}.${extension}"
    touch filename${i}
    echo "this rox" > filename${i}
done
```

This code will create 20 files and **dynamically** set 20 variables. Of course you could use an array, but I'm just showing you the feature :). Note that you can use the variables $filename1, $filename2, $filename3... because they were created with evaluate command. In this case I'm just creating files, but you could use to create dynamically arguments to the commands, and then execute in background.

Answer (score 2):

For example you have a start program named run.sh to start it working at background do the following command line.
./run.sh  &>/dev/null &