# Send a running function to background in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

As the title says, I want to send a running function to the background. Something like

```
function myfunc {
    some_command | while read line
    #some_command must be running indefinitely
    do
        #if some condition on ${line} satisfies
        #Do something and go to background
    done
}
```

Is it possible?

I know that it is possible to call a function directly & to directly run it in the background. That is pretty obvious. This is not duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683910/executing-shell-command-in-background-from-script).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [executing shell command in background from script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683910/executing-shell-command-in-background-from-script)

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? You can call your function form a separated bash script an call this with an ampersand. Then your function is run in the background.

Comment: Why not `while true; do if ...; then do_something & break; fi`

Comment: @WilliamPursell I edited the question. Now it should be clear why I am asking.

Comment: I don't know if you can send a function to the background. But you surely can send a process or the script to the background. You just need to send an SIGSTOP signal.

Comment: @Aditya SIGSTOP sends it to background and stops. I need it to be running in background.

Comment: This really doesn't make any sense.  The net effect is that `myfunc` runs in the background, but the caller waits until the first time 'some condition' is satisfied.  To accomplish that, have the caller block on a read from a pipe, then  run the function in the background and have it write to that pipe when the condition is met.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Can you explain it clearly in an answer. The condition is on ${line} if that is not clear.

Comment: What is it you want in the background?  It's not at all clear why you don't just invoke the function in the background initially, or why you can't just do `if condition; then do_something & fi` and do something in the background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple command creates a process in background and waits for its termination, in your case the caller must continue when a condition is met asynchronously with callee which continues running.

This can be done with kill -STOP (caller blocks himself) and kill -CONT (callee unblock caller)

```
function myfunc {
    some_command | while read line
    #some_command must be running indefinitely
    do
        #if some condition on ${line} satisfies
        kill -CONT $$
    done & kill -STOP $$
}
```

Comment: FYI, the `function` keyword makes this code needlessly noncompliant with the POSIX sh specification -- it would be portable to a wider array of shells if the first line were `myfunc() {`, with the `function` keyword removed and the `()` syntax added.