# How to keep the internal shell script running while the main shell script ends?

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, unix

I am trying to create one script which check for a running process and start it if it is not running.

Here is **test.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
if pgrep infiloop > /dev/null ;
  then
  echo "Process is running."
else
   exec /u/team/infiloop.sh > /u/team/infiloopOutput.txt
  echo "Process was not running."
fi
```

And **infiloop.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

while true
do
 echo "helllo"
 sleep 2
done
```

Now when i run the 1st script , it starts the script but after it start it doesn't allow me to run another command.

**Output:**

```
[user@host ~]$ ./checkforRunningJob.sh

^C
```

I have to press Ctrl+C, Ctrl+Z, and once i do that my infinite script also stop.

Could you please check.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [executing shell command in background from script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683910/executing-shell-command-in-background-from-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the process in the background with `&`:

```
#!/bin/bash

if pgrep infiloop > /dev/null ;
then
    echo "Process is running."
else
    exec /u/team/infiloop.sh > /u/team/infiloopOutput.txt &
    echo "Process was not running, started process $!"
fi
```

Comment: What did I do wrong? I don't understand the downvote...

Comment: Maybe they do it bcoz of someone already commented it. + 1 from my side.

Comment: @Thinker That someone was me but I've removed the comment now. I don't want to get downvoted for "stealing" my own stuff :-) Thanks for the +1.