# Run firebase emulators + vitest at once

Tags: yaml, github-actions, firebase-tools

I'm trying to run two jobs at the same time.
First I need to run `firebase emulators` and when the ports are open, I need to run vitest.

This is what I'm doing at the moment:

```yaml
name: Run Tests

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [develop]
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  job1:
    name: Run Emulator
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Use Node.js 18.14.0
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 18.14.0
          cache: 'npm'
      - name: Execute Emulator
        env:
          VITE_RELEASE_STAGE: testing
        run: |
          npm ci
          npm install --save firebase-tools
          npm run emulators
  job2:
    name: Run Unit Tests
    needs: job1
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Use Node.js 18.14.0
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 18.14.0
          cache: 'npm'
      - name: Execute Unit Tests
        env:
          VITE_RELEASE_STAGE: testing
        run: |
          npm ci
          npm run test
```

The doors open perfectly, but the second job never runs.

Here lies my doubt. Because if I don't use `needs` the two will run at the same time and I will get an error in job2 because the ports will not be open in job 1.

[image: Running emulators]

I would like to run job 2 as soon as the emulator ports are open and finish job 1 only after job 2 finishes.

Does anyone know how I can resolve this?

[image: Running jobs]

---

**EDIT**

These are the two executed scripts that are in my `package.json`:

```json
"test": "vitest",
"emulators": "firebase emulators:start --project celebrityfanalizer --import emulatorData"
```

Comment: GHA jobs run in different runners. In your workflow, the first job never finishes. You can combine both jobs, run emulators in the background, and then run tests in the same job.

Comment: I got it, that's my intention. But how do I run emulators in the background?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683910/executing-shell-command-in-background-from-script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your workflow, the `job1` never finishes because the emulators are running in it and that's why the `job2` never runs when you add its dependency on `job1` i.e. `needs: job1`.

You need to combine both jobs in one:

1. set up the environment
2. start the emulators in the background
3. wait for the emulators to start

   - add some delay (along with a dump of its STDOUT/STDERR to a file and keep checking its contents for success logs e.g. `"Emulator hub running"`)
4. and, finally, run tests

Here's an example with a delay of 1 minute after starting the emulators in the background:

```yaml
name: Run Tests in the Emulators

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [develop]
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  ci:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Set up NodeJS 18.14.0
      uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: 18.14.0
        cache: 'npm'

    - name: Start the emulators and run tests
      env:
        VITE_RELEASE_STAGE: testing
      run: |
        npm ci
        npm install --save firebase-tools
        nohup npm run emulators &> emulators.log &
        sleep 1m
        npm run test
```

Relevant:

- [executing shell command in background from script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683910/executing-shell-command-in-background-from-script)

---

Apart from that, you can use [`jobs.<job_id>.services`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idservices) and run the emulators in a container if it's available.

---

**UPDATE**

As pointed out by [sceee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4796491/sceee) in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75494249/run-firebase-emulators-vitest-at-once/75516641?noredirect=1#comment137264019_75516641) below, alternatively you may use [`firebase emulators:exec`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#run_the_emulator_suite) by configuring it under `scripts` in your `package.json`:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "test:emulators": "firebase emulators:exec \"npm test\""
  }
}
```

and then invoke it as needed:

```bash
npm run test:emulators
```

This will automate the process of starting the emulators, running tests, and then stopping the emulators after the tests are complete.

Comment: @ARNON: You're welcome! You may observe and adjust `sleep` accordingly. Maybe, you need a lower sleep time in between. I just put `sleep 1m` after looking at `2m 53s` in your snapshot. Most probably, it was due to the fact that you let it run a bit and then took the snapshot.

Comment: Thanks for the tipo. At this moment 1m is perfect.

Comment: Instead of waiting an arbitrary time like 1 minute for the emulators to start, there is [`firebase emulators:exec`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#run_the_emulator_suite) for exactly this purpose. Just declare an npm script like this `"test:emulators": "firebase emulators:exec \"npm test\"",` in your package.json and start it using `npm run test:emulators`. It will spin up the emulators and once they are ready, execute your npm `test` script. After it ends, it will shut down the emulators again.

Comment: @sceee: Have you tested this yourself? It says "If you want to run a test suite or testing script **after** the emulators have started, use the `emulators:exec` command". That sounds like the emulators need to be started first separately i.e. `firebase emulators:start` needs to added in the script too, right? But, as per your comment, "It will spin up the emulators" too.

Comment: @Azeem yeah, I'm using `firebase emulators:exec ...` a lot (e.g. in CI with `--import=...` to initialize the Firestore emulator with mock data) and it spins up the emulators, runs the script given as argument and stops the emulators again after that script exited. So you don't have to worry about starting, waiting until they are ready and exiting the emulators again.

Comment: @sceee: Thank you for sharing this! I've updated my answer to incorporate this also.